# Add "element" with all childs on XML File with etree.ElementTree - Python

Tags: python, xml, append, addition

I have a XML file and I need add new elements with all childs.

I have a element "deviceset" with name R and I and need add another one with name "R_100_5" and "?_VALUE" = 100 and "?_TOL" = 5.

How I can "copy" and paste my "R" element and replace name, "?_VALUE", and "?_TOL" ?

PS: To "tag" the elementos deviceset from my root I need this iterations: root[0][3][4][0].tag

Example XML file input:

```
<deviceset name="R" prefix="R" uservalue="yes">
    <description>Resistor Fixed - ANSI</description>
    <gates>
        <gate name="G$1" symbol="R" x="0" y="0"/>
    </gates>
    <devices>
        <device name="SMD_0402(M1005)" package="F_SMD_0402(M1005)">
            <connects>
                <connect gate="G$1" pad="1" pin="1"/>
                <connect gate="G$1" pad="2" pin="2"/>
            </connects>
            <package3dinstances>
                <package3dinstance package3d_urn="urn:adsk.eagle:package:16378568/2"/>
            </package3dinstances>
            <technologies>
                <technology name="_">

                    <attribute name="_TOL" value="?_Tol"/>
                    <attribute name="_TYPE" value="?_Type"/>
                    <attribute name="_VALUE" value="?_Value"/>
                </technology>
            </technologies>
        </device>
        <device name="SMD_0603(M1608)" package="F_SMD_0603(M1608)">
            <connects>
                <connect gate="G$1" pad="1" pin="1"/>
                <connect gate="G$1" pad="2" pin="2"/>
            </connects>
            <package3dinstances>
                <package3dinstance package3d_urn="urn:adsk.eagle:package:16378565/2"/>
            </package3dinstances>
            <technologies>
                <technology name="_">
                    <attribute name="_TOL" value="?_Tol"/>
                    <attribute name="_TYPE" value="?_Type"/>
                    <attribute name="_VALUE" value="?_Value"/>
                </technology>
            </technologies>
        </device>
    </devices>
    <spice>
        <pinmapping spiceprefix="R">
            <pinmap gate="G$1" pin="1" pinorder="1"/>
            <pinmap gate="G$1" pin="2" pinorder="2"/>
        </pinmapping>
    </spice>
</deviceset>
```

Example XML file output:

```
<deviceset name="R" prefix="R" uservalue="yes">
    <description>&lt;B&gt;Resistor Fixed - ANSI</description>
    <gates>
        <gate name="G$1" symbol="R" x="0" y="0"/>
    </gates>
    <devices>
        <device name="SMD_0402(M1005)" package="F_SMD_0402(M1005)">
            <connects>
                <connect gate="G$1" pad="1" pin="1"/>
                <connect gate="G$1" pad="2" pin="2"/>
            </connects>
            <package3dinstances>
                <package3dinstance package3d_urn="urn:adsk.eagle:package:16378568/2"/>
            </package3dinstances>
            <technologies>
                <technology name="_">

                    <attribute name="_TOL" value="?_Tol"/>
                    <attribute name="_VALUE" value="?_Value"/>
                </technology>
            </technologies>
        </device>
        <device name="SMD_0603(M1608)" package="F_SMD_0603(M1608)">
            <connects>
                <connect gate="G$1" pad="1" pin="1"/>
                <connect gate="G$1" pad="2" pin="2"/>
            </connects>
            <package3dinstances>
                <package3dinstance package3d_urn="urn:adsk.eagle:package:16378565/2"/>
            </package3dinstances>
            <technologies>
                <technology name="_">
                    <attribute name="_TOL" value="?_Tol"/>
                    <attribute name="_VALUE" value="?_Value"/>
                </technology>
            </technologies>
        </device>
    </devices>
    <spice>
        <pinmapping spiceprefix="R">
            <pinmap gate="G$1" pin="1" pinorder="1"/>
            <pinmap gate="G$1" pin="2" pinorder="2"/>
        </pinmapping>
    </spice>
</deviceset>
<deviceset name="R_100_5" prefix="R" uservalue="yes">
    <description>&lt;B&gt;Resistor Fixed - ANSI</description>
    <gates>
        <gate name="G$1" symbol="R" x="0" y="0"/>
    </gates>
    <devices>
        <device name="SMD_0402(M1005)" package="F_SMD_0402(M1005)">
            <connects>
                <connect gate="G$1" pad="1" pin="1"/>
                <connect gate="G$1" pad="2" pin="2"/>
            </connects>
            <package3dinstances>
                <package3dinstance package3d_urn="urn:adsk.eagle:package:16378568/2"/>
            </package3dinstances>
            <technologies>
                <technology name="_">
                    <attribute name="_TOL" value="5"/>
                    <attribute name="_VALUE" value="100"/>
                </technology>
            </technologies>
        </device>
        <device name="SMD_0603(M1608)" package="F_SMD_0603(M1608)">
            <connects>
                <connect gate="G$1" pad="1" pin="1"/>
                <connect gate="G$1" pad="2" pin="2"/>
            </connects>
            <package3dinstances>
                <package3dinstance package3d_urn="urn:adsk.eagle:package:16378565/2"/>
            </package3dinstances>
            <technologies>
                <technology name="_">
                    <attribute name="_TOL" value="5"/>
                    <attribute name="_VALUE" value="100"/>
                </technology>
            </technologies>
        </device>
    </devices>
    <spice>
        <pinmapping spiceprefix="R">
            <pinmap gate="G$1" pin="1" pinorder="1"/>
            <pinmap gate="G$1" pin="2" pinorder="2"/>
        </pinmapping>
    </spice>
</deviceset>
```